# Video apps all failing?

Tags: youtube, video-streaming

I've recently noticed a whole collection of video streaming apps all failing at once on my Samsung S8+. YouTube, Amazon Prime Video and All4 are all now dead -Amazon will start up but not play anything, streamed or downloaded, while the others won't even start up. Apps have been updated, the device restarted.

It seems unlikely that three very similar apps have all died at the same time while the rest are fine without there being a common cause. Is there anything I could usefully check to try and get things working again?

Comment: Network connection of any type or none makes no difference. YouTube videos are payable in the browser.

Comment: Real strange! Even though it's 4 apps at once that are not working, I would still try clearing data for them and see what happens. *Settings > application manger > YouTube > storage > clear data*

Comment: If you can get an ADB logcat excerpt when the apps fail to start or play, that should be quite helpful towards pinpointing the culprit.

Comment: Well that's odd. Restarting didn't work. Reinstalling didn't work. Clearing the data didn't work. Restarting again having done all of the above now did, though...